# Why is my code not saving data to the Kinvey Backend?

Tags: swift, data-storage, kinvey

I have a viewController that has three textfields (name, email & seats) and a Date picker. Below there is a button that is connected as an outlet to send a reservation to the backend where it should be registered. I tried several things already but for some reason the data is not saved. I am connected to the backend because i can see the Api calls and data storage in Bytes.... Could you please check my code?

```
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    self.sendReservation.addTarget(self, action: "sendBooking:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    let reservation = Booking()
    reservation.name = userName.text
    reservation.email = userEmail.text
    reservation.seats = userSeat.text
    reservation.date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1352149171) //sample date

          func sendBooking (sender: UIButton) {

        KCSUser.loginWithUsername("admin", password: "leden1234",
            withCompletionBlock: { (user: KCSUser!, errorOrNil: NSError!, result: KCSUserActionResult) -> Void in
                if errorOrNil == nil {

        let store = KCSAppdataStore.storeWithOptions([
            KCSStoreKeyCollectionName : "userReservation",
            KCSStoreKeyCollectionTemplateClass : Booking.self
            ])

                    store.saveObject(
                        reservation,
                        withCompletionBlock: { (objectsOrNil: [AnyObject]!, errorOrNil: NSError!) -> Void in
                            if errorOrNil != nil {
                                //save failed
                                NSLog("Save failed, with error: %@", errorOrNil.localizedFailureReason!)
                            } else {
                                //save was successful
                                NSLog("Successfully saved event (id='%@').", (objectsOrNil[0] as! NSObject).kinveyObjectId())
                            }
                        },
                        withProgressBlock: nil
                    ) } else {

                    NSLog("User was not registered: %@", errorOrNil.localizedFailureReason!)

                }

                })
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

All Kinvey requests must be made using an authorized user, if a user doesn't exist, an automatic user generation facility exists.

**Make sure you are an active user i.e. you have logged in before making any Kinvey calls.** I have tried your code and it worked fine. Try following implementation :

```
KCSUser.loginWithUsername(
        "kinvey",
        password: "12345",
        withCompletionBlock: { (user: KCSUser!, errorOrNil: NSError!, result: KCSUserActionResult) -> Void in
            if errorOrNil == nil {

                //the log-in was successful and the user is now the active user and credentials saved
                // Put your code to save the object here

            } else {

                //there was an error with the update save

            }
        }
    )
```

For more details,check http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/guides/users#.

**If above information doesn't help, let me know what error you are getting in "errorOrNil.localizedFailureReason".**

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, it still does not send any data to the Backend.... I added the loginWithUsername above the store data function...What am I doing wrong here? I create a active user and changed the details of the login in my code to those details.

Comment: What error you are getting in "errorOrNil.localizedFailureReason"?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this its work with me fine

```
KCSUser.userWithUsername(Username_user.text!, password: Password.text!, fieldsAndValues: [KCSUserAttributeEmail : Email.text!,
                KCSUserAttributeGivenname : UserName.text! ,KCSUserAttributeSurname : SureName.text!],
 withCompletionBlock: { (user: KCSUser!, errorOrNil: NSError!, result: KCSUserActionResult) -> Void in

 if errorOrNil == nil {

}else{

}

})
```